# How Can I compare two tables?

Tags: php, mysql

```
    <?php
    $hostdb = "localhost";
    $userdb = "root"; 
    $passdb = "";
    $namedb = "dctdb3"; 


    $dbhandle = new mysqli($hostdb, $userdb, $passdb, $namedb);

    if ($dbhandle->connect_error) {
    exit("There was an error with your connection: ".$dbhandle->connect_error);
    }

    $query = "SELECT msdnd_oct.id as id1, msakl_oct.id as id2, msdnd_oct.sold as sold1, msakl_oct.sold as sold2, msdnd_oct.sales as sales1, msakl_oct.sales as sales2 FROM msdnd_oct inner join msakl_oct ON msakl_oct.id=msdnd_oct.id"; 

?>
```

The code above is the only thing I have found from searches but it's not what i'm looking for.

Hi there I have been searching for awhile but cannot find what I'm looking for.
I have two tables named "msdnd_oct" and "msakl_oct".
They are both basically monthly summaries.
I want to make a comparison between the two tables. Display both tables together. So that I can see which table has more 'sold' items. So for example, if the table 'msdnd_oct' has 40 'sold' and 'msakl_oct' has 39. I can see that dnd has more.
The three rows that I want to display is 'id', 'sold' and 'sales'

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Please try to explain better what you want. Post your table structure with sample data and some of the expected results.

Comment: Yes... Your question is very unclear... What rows/columns you want to compare? how's the table structure? How do you compare the rows (example t1.sold > t2.sold or t1.sales = t2.sales)?

Comment: I want to make a comparison between the two tables. Display both tables together. So that I can see which table has more 'sold' items. So for example, if the table 'msdnd_oct' has 40 'sold' and 'msakl_oct' has 39. I can see that dnd has more. Not sure if that's clear enough. Sorry. and many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you want something like this.

```
"SELECT 

     msdnd_oct.id as id1,
     msakl_oct.id as id2,

     msdnd_oct.sold as sold1,
     msakl_oct.sold as sold2,

     msdnd_oct.sales as sales1,
     msakl_oct.sales as sales2

     FROM msdnd_oct inner join msakl_oct ON msakl_oct.id=msdnd_oct.id"
```

If you want to compare total sales, or sold items you can use **GROUP BY**
Or If you simply want to combine to tables without joining them you can use **UNION**

You can execute above query in php as below

```
$query =  "SELECT 

         msdnd_oct.id as id1,
         msakl_oct.id as id2,

         msdnd_oct.sold as sold1,
         msakl_oct.sold as sold2,

         msdnd_oct.sales as sales1,
         msakl_oct.sales as sales2

         FROM msdnd_oct inner join msakl_oct ON msakl_oct.id=msdnd_oct.id";

 $result = mysqli_query($dbhandle,$query);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "id1: " . $row["id"]. " - id2: " . $row["id2"]. " <br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
```

I encourage you learn much more about connecting to Mysql, retrieving data from Mysql with PHP. Take a look at below links. Then you will get the clear idea of how to do your given task.

[Learn about Php & Mysql](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_intro.asp)

[Learn about GROUP BY statement](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp)

[Learn ab obout UNION operator](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp)

Comment: Can you please teach me how to write that in PHP code? Thanks!